# Django project with Google Calendars API

Tags: python, django, api, calendar, google-calendar-api

I have been working on a Django application which uses the Google Calendars API to manage meetings (add meetings to a user's calendar, send meeting invitations to people etc).

There were some inconsistencies however with calendar events not appearing in some users calendars. I started looking into this, and having not had the Google Calendars API running within my development environment previously (although I had access to the code used for the calendars on the application in the status that it was in prior to when I started working on it), I followed parts of the tutorials at developers.google.com to try and get the existing Calendar API up and running on my development machine, but have somehow managed to break the working code when trying to add the Calendars API to it.

When I now try to browse to my website by typing www.mysite.co.uk in the browser, I get an error page which says:

> NameError at /projects/my-projects/
>
> global name 'h_user' is not defined
>
> Request Method:   GET
>
> Request URL:  http://www.mysite.co.uk/projects/my-projects/
>
> Django Version:   1.9.1
>
> Exception Type:   NameError
>
> Exception Value:
>   global name 'h_user' is not defined
>
> Exception Location:   /code/moon/core/templatetags/getters.py in get_invite_details, line 153
>
> Python Executable:    /usr/bin/python
>
> Python Version:   2.7.6
>
> Python Path:
>   ['/code/moon',
>    '/usr/local/bin',
>    '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg',
>    '/usr/lib/python2.7',
>    '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
>    '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
>    '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
>    '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
>    '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
>    '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
>
> Server time:  Wed, 11 Jan 2017 09:08:01 +0000

Firstly, I don't get why typing the 'root' address of my website (www.mysite.co.uk) is returning a 'Request URL' of www.mysite.co.uk/projects/my-projects - that is one of the pages on the site, but is not the 'Home' page, and is only accessed when clicking the 'Projects' link from the menu. Why am I being routed to this particular page?

The error page in my browser shows the details:

> Error during template rendering
>
> In template /code/moon/projects/templates/projects/my_projects.html, error at line 0
>
> global name 'h_user' is not defined

and the 'Traceback' indicates that there are error in the following files:

core/templatetags/getters.py:

```
def get_invite_details(user, responded=False):
    from calendar_api.manager import get_event
    from django.utils.dateparse import parse_datetime
    from events.models import Meeting

    if user.is_authenticated():
        employee = user.employee
        if responded: e_invites = employee.event_notifications.all()
        else: e_invites = employee.event_notifications.filter(responded=False)
        events_data = [get_event(i.calendar_id, i.event_id) for i in e_invites]
        invites = []
        for event in events_data:
            if event and event['id']:
                invite = [event['summary'] or '', parse_datetime(event['start'].get('date') or event['start'].get('dateTime')) or '']
                m = Meeting.objects.filter(event_id=event['id'])
                if m:
                    m = m[0].event_creator
                    print "m'", m
                    invite += [m]
                else:
                    creator = Employee.objects.filter(calendar_id=event.get('organizer').get('email'))
                    if creator: invite += [creator.first()]
                    else: invite += [h_user]
                invite += [event['id']]
                invite += [e_invites.get(event_id=event['id']).responded]

                if responded and is_attending(event, employee.calendar_id): invite += [1]

                invites += [invite]

            return invites
```

The 'Traceback' indicates that the error in this file is on the line:

```
else: invite += [h_user]
```

projects/views.py:

```
def my_projects(request):
    context = {'projects': request.user.employee.settings.allocated_projects.all()}
    if request.is_ajax() and request.GET.get('filter'):
        return JsonResponse(filter_projects_name(request, context['projects'], 'projects/includes/project_cards.html'))
    return render(request, 'projects/my_projects.html', context)
```

The 'Traceback' indicates that the error in this file is on the line:

```
return render(request, 'projects/my_projects.html', context)
```

mysite/middleware.py:

```
def process_view(self,request,view_func,view_args,view_kwargs):
    # An exception match should immediately return None
    for path in self.exceptions:
        if path.match(request.path): return None            
    # Requests matching a restricted URL pattern are returned 
    # wrapped with the permission_required decorator
    for rule in self.restricted:
        url, required_permission = rule[0], rule[1]
        if url.match(request.path): 
            return permission_required(required_permission)(view_func)(request,*view_args,**view_kwargs)             
    # Explicitly return None for all non-matching requests
    return None
```

The 'Traceback' indicates that the error in this file is on the line:

```
return permission_required(required_permission)(view_func)(request,*view_args,**view_kwargs)
```

I understand the error about the variable `h_user` not being defined- and having looked through the file where it is used, I can't see anywhere that it is defined... but I don't understand why I'm now getting this error, when I wasn't prior to trying to use the Google Calendars API- I don't think it's something that's come from the API, as the variable name would indicate that it is something to do with the software that I am working on, so it's likely that this was written by the person working on the software before I took over from them. But how/ why would having tried integrating/ using the Calendars API have broken this?

If I try viewing a local copy of my project in the browser, from "localhost:8000", I am taken to the same page as it is trying to direct me to on the 'live' version (localhost:8000/projects/my-projects/), but it works on my localhost, and I am able to fully interact with the page. In fact, I am able to fully interact with pretty much the whole site on my localhost- except if I click the 'Calendars' option on the menu, and I am then shown an error message in the browser:

> RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /events/cal/2017/1/
>
> Project has no taskgroup.

How can I fix this, to get Google Calendars working correctly with my site?

Comment: That reference is inside a few if blocks, so presumably you previously never hit that combination of circumstances: either there were always matching meetings, or the employee records always had a creator.

Comment: I do not expect the 'Calendars' part of the site to work on my local branch- as it requires a connection with the Google Calendars API, which it doesn't have locally. When previously making any changes to anything to do with the calendars, I have made the changes locally, and then tested them on the live server with a 'test' project. What I don't understand, is why I'm no longer able to view any of the other pages on the live version of the site, even though everyone else is...?

Comment: I think there possibly might be an issue with my Django 'user' profile which is preventing me from accessing the application- I usually use Chrome as my browser, and have selected that it 'remember my user name & password' for my site, so I am usually logged into the site automatically. If I type "www.mysite.co.uk" into Chrome at the moment, I am automatically given this `NameError` page that I have described above.

Comment: However, if I try browsing to "www.mysite.co.uk" in Safari, I am taken to the 'log in' page for www.mysite.co.uk... if I log in, I am then given the same error page as I see in Chrome, which says that `user is not defined`...  is it possible that my Django user profile/ account has become corrupted, and that's why I can't access the site, but everyone else can?